# Using RowNumber and Partition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Consider this code:

```
Select U.[user_id] As UserID
  Max(AL.entry_dt) As LastLoginDate
From Users U with (nolock)
  Inner Join activity_log AL with (nolock) On AL.[user_id] = U.[user_id] 
                                              And AL.activity_type = 'LOGIN'
                                              And U.external_user = 1
Group By U.[user_id]
Having Max(al.entry_dt) < GetDate() - 30
Order By U.[user_id]
```

I was curious if the Row_Number / Partition could be used here?  Perhaps to make this more effective, or if it can be used at all?

Essentially, I want 1 row per user with the last instance the user logged in where the user **hasn't logged in during the last 30 days**.

Bring on the pain.....

Comment: Cross apply and top with correlation

Comment: Again this would *not* eliminate users that did log on in the last 30 days.

Comment: I'm a little unsure if you want all users even if they haven't logged in in 30 days and show no activity if they haven't: or if you want only users who have had activity in the past 30 days.

Comment: For the last time this would *not* eliminate users that did log on in the last 30 days.   Test it.

Comment: @xQbert I do.  the business requirement for external users is to disable them if they haven't logged in within the last 30 days.

Comment: @Paparazzi No, it just gives me a list of all external users who haven't logged in within the last 30 days.  I have tested it....  Would still need an update statement and a where clause to account for if they are active or not.

Comment: It does NOTHING to ELIMINATE users.  It only eliminates dates.  All it does is give you the most recent date that is more than 30 days past.

Comment: @MisterPositive What Paparazzi is saying is that there is a difference between `Where AL.entry_dt < GetDate() - 30` and `having max(al.entry_dt) < GetDate() - 30`

Comment: @Paparazzi Sometimes it takes a hammer to get through...thanks for enduring...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CROSS APPLY or OUTER APPLY allow you to return n records from correlated query for each record in related table.    I think cross apply is what you want since if a user hasn't logged in in the past 30 days you don't want to see them at all in results.  Cross apply similar to inner join but runs correlation query for each record related table. OUTER Apply similar to OUTER join so it returns all records from related table and only those that match in the correlated query.

So in the below example, for each user, return the top 1 record in descending order of entry_dT. for each related user.  Outer apply would resemble a left join so all users would be returned even if no activity occurred.

MODIFIED DEMO: http://rextester.com/UQEI69366 (all 3 below) again thx to SQLZim for tester/data

```
SELECT U.[user_id] As UserID
     , AL.entry_dt As LastLoginDate
FROM Users U with (nolock)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT top 1 * 
             FROM activity_log IAL 
             WHERE U.User_ID = IAL.User_ID
               AND IAL.activity_type = 'LOGIN'

             ORDER BY IAL.entry_DT Desc) AL
WHERE U.external_user = 1
  AND IAL.entry_dt < GetDate() - 30
ORDER BY U.[user_id]
```

If all you're after is users who haven't logged in in the past 30 days...
a simple not exists seems like it would work.  Who cares about the date time if they have; you're just after a list of users who haven't logged in in 30 days.

```
SELECT U.[user_id] As UserID
FROM Users U
WHERE not exists (SELECT *
                  FROM activity_log IAL 
                  WHERE IAL.activity_type = 'LOGIN'
                    AND IAL.entry_dt > GetDate() - 30
                    AND IAL.[user_id] = U.[user_id])

  AND U.external_user = 1
ORDER BY U.[user_id]
```

a simple left join would work as well  (return all external users who have not had a login in 30 days from present date.

```
SELECT U.[user_id] As UserID
FROM Users U with (nolock)
LEFT JOIN activity_log AL 
  ON AL.[user_id] = U.[user_id] 
 AND AL.activity_type = 'LOGIN'
 AND AL.entry_dt > GetDate() - 30
WHERE U.external_user = 1
  and AL.user_ID is null
ORDER BY U.[user_id]
```

Comment: Yeah don't need the `on` just noticed it. and don't need the `group by` anymore.

Comment: Slower perhaps; but if you wanted the top 3 most recent entries instead of the most current this gives flexibility.

Comment: @MisterPositive also why do you need the datetime of the log at all.  If a user hasn't logged in in 30 days, they wouldn't have a log record so why not just use an not exists? (2nd sql above)

Comment: You could do that too.  I was just trying to learn about the other features.

Comment: `Not exists`, `not in`, `LEFT JOIN (users with activity in 30 days) where Log.user_ID is null`   `cross apply`... `row_number`... these are the common patterns I typically use.

Comment: updated the rextester demo in my answer with better example data. If you move the `where entry_dt < getdate()-30` from your first query to outside the `cross apply()` then it would be the correct list

Comment: ah thx corrected my cross apply example.  I should know to test my edge cases better.

Comment: @xQbert +1 & on a related note, if you don't want to have to keep updating your rextester links, you can use `edit mode` https://i.gyazo.com/0f20c6eb245f9b265ebb9a4a0f959dc1.png which lets you rename it as well.

Answer (score 3):

To use the result of the `row_number()` in a `where` clause, wrap the query in a subquery/derived table or [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

Original answer for users that have logged in within the last 30 days:

```
select UserId, LastLoginDate 
from (
    Select 
        U.[user_id] As UserID
      , AL.entry_dt As LastLoginDate
      , rn = row_number() over(partition by u.user_id order by AL.entry_dt desc)
    From Users U with (nolock)
      Inner Join activity_log AL with (nolock) 
        On AL.[user_id] = U.[user_id] 
        And AL.activity_type = 'LOGIN'
        And U.external_user = 1
    Where AL.entry_dt > GetDate() - 30 -- swapped < for >
  ) sub
where rn = 1
Order By sub.[userid]
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/XZU40394

returns:

```
+--------+---------------+
| UserId | LastLoginDate |
+--------+---------------+
|      1 | 2017-09-13    |
|      2 | 2017-09-10    |
|      3 | 2017-09-07    |
+--------+---------------+
```

---

Updated answer for users who have not logged in in the last 30 days:

```
select UserId, LastLoginDate 
from (
    Select 
        U.[user_id] As UserID
      , AL.entry_dt As LastLoginDate
      , rn = row_number() over(partition by u.user_id order by AL.entry_dt desc)
    From Users U with (nolock)
      Inner Join activity_log AL with (nolock) 
        On AL.[user_id] = U.[user_id] 
        And AL.activity_type = 'LOGIN'
        And U.external_user = 1
  ) sub
where rn = 1
  and lastlogindate < getdate() - 30
Order By [userid]
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/XZU40394

returns:

```
+--------+---------------+
| UserId | LastLoginDate |
+--------+---------------+
|      4 | 2016-09-13    |
|      6 | 2016-09-10    |
+--------+---------------+
```

from test setup:

```
create table users (user_id int, external_user bit)
create table activity_log (user_id int, activity_type varchar(32), entry_dt date)

insert into users values (1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(5,0),(6,1)
insert into activity_log values 
 (1,'login','20170913') ,(1,'login','20170912') ,(1,'login','20170911'),(1,'login','20160908')  
,(2,'login','20170910') ,(2,'login','20170909') ,(2,'login','20170908')
,(3,'login','20170907') ,(3,'login','20170906') ,(3,'login','20170905') 
,(4,'login','20160913') ,(4,'login','20160912') ,(4,'login','20160908') 
,(5,'login','20160910') ,(5,'login','20160909') ,(5,'login','20160908') 
,(6,'login','20160910') ,(6,'login','20160909') ,(6,'login','20160908')
```

---

To correct your query in the question, move your `where` to `having` like so:

```
Select U.[user_id] As UserID
  ,Max(AL.entry_dt) As LastLoginDate
From Users U with (nolock)
  Inner Join activity_log AL with (nolock) On AL.[user_id] = U.[user_id] 
                                              And AL.activity_type = 'LOGIN'
                                              And U.external_user = 1
Group By U.[user_id]
having max(al.entry_dt) < GetDate() - 30
Order By U.[user_id]
```

Comment: I get an error with this code :  Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
The multi-part identifier "u.user_id" could not be bound,

Comment: @MisterPositive sorry, corrected the table alias in the `order by`

Comment: Even if I remove the order by, now I get only one row.  Not one row per user

Comment: Still only returns one records, and where clause fails.

Comment: I see, I tripped you up with my questions wording.  Thank you!

Comment: @MisterPositive Ya, I didn't read "the last time the user logged in if past 30 days" as "the last time the user logged in where the user hasn't logged in during the last 30 days" -- and i tripped up on the switch from user_id to userid in the `order by`

Answer (score 1):

> I was curious if the Row_Number / Partition could be used here?  Perhaps to make this more effective, or if it can be used at all?

I prefer group by in your case than row number since row number needs additional index than group by.Read below to know more

Assuming you use the same query you posted,below are the indexes needed

for users table..

```
create index nci_test on 
dbo.usertable(userid,external_login)
```

For activity log table, you will need to know more about the data..

**Ex:**
if join filters out more rows than where,then  index can be

```
create index nci_test1 on 
    dbo.actvititlog(userid,entry_Dt,activity_type )
```

if entry_dt column filters out more rows,then leading column can be entry_Dt in above index

if you use RowNumber,it will need a POC index and your query spreads across two tables,so this can't be done

Comment: So my original code is best over attempting to use Row_Number and Partition?

Comment: I think so  and i prefer it over Rownumber solution

Comment: `Is there a way to use it` you mean row number solution

Comment: Yes, row_number() partition

Comment: yes you can use it  and sqlzim solution should work .Sqlzim's solution also returns one row for all users that are left after filtering and joining

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154376/discussion-between-thegameiswar-and-mister-positive).